# DataContractSerializer deserializing Known Types

Tags: c#, deserialization, datacontractserializer

I have an object structure as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Condition<T>
{
    [DataMember] public string Id { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "AttributeEqualTo", Namespace = "")]
public class AttributeEqualTo<T> : Condition<T>
{
    [DataMember] public string AttributeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string ExpectedValue { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "AttributeNotEqualTo", Namespace = "")]
public class AttributeNotEqualTo<T> : AttributeEqualTo<T>
{
}

[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Conditions", Namespace = "")]
[KnownType("KnownTypes")]
public class ConditionSet<T> : Collection<Condition<T>>
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> KnownTypes()
    {
        var knownTypes = new Collection<Type>
                             {
                                 typeof(AttributeEqualTo<T>),
                                 typeof(AttributeNotEqualTo<T>),
                             };
        return knownTypes;
    }
}
```

Given the following XML:

```
  <Conditions>
    <AttributeEqualTo>
      <Id>C1</Id>
      <AttributeName>Foo</AttributeName>
      <ExpectedValue>Bar</ExpectedValue>
    </AttributeEqualTo>
    <AttributeNotEqualTo>
      <Id>C2</Id>
      <AttributeName>Blah</AttributeName>
      <ExpectedValue>Value</ExpectedValue>
    </AttributeNotEqualTo>
  </Conditions>
```

When I deserialize it I expected to get a Collection of Conditions that includes each of the two defined in the XML. The problem I am having is that I get the collection, but it is empty.

I have tested the ability to deserialize the conditions individually and it seems to work fine.

I was using the following for reference of how to define the contract, [Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx)

Comment: Did you construct that XML manually?  If you try generating XML with the DataContractSerializer, then deserialize it again, it works.  The difference seems to be in the `Condition` entries, which are specified in the form `<Condition i:type="AttributeEqualTo">` rather than `<AttributeEqualTo>`.

Comment: Yes, I saw that as well. I am trying to make tweaks to the contract to get the desired XML.

Comment: Why are you using generics when `T` isn't actually referred to anywhere inside the class?  Did you intend for `ExpectedValue` eventually to be type `T`?

Comment: There is another method that isn't included that takes an instance of T as a parameter.

Comment: I would recommend converting the code to use `XmlSerializer`, which will give you more control over the namespaces.  Also, getting rid of generics in your XML classes will help a lot.  You may need to use some sort of Adapter pattern to translate objects back and forth between your serializing layer and your domain classes.

Comment: Suggestion don't use Known Types , Collections etc or you will be in a world of hurt these things cannot be represented nicely in XML in an open way .   Tried it once Seen it tried many times.   I pretty much stick to simple custom messages now .

Answer (score 0):

Try removing generics - this often breaks serialization.